# how to retrive the data from database and show on JLabel in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am doing project in Netbeans and want to show the employee details on `JLabel` while selecting the employee from `JComboBox`.

I tried... but no effect on the frame.

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
   try {                  

                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                
                   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tnpcb","root","");
                   String sql="select curr_no,receive_date from tapal where user_id='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'";


                   pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

                   rs=pst.executeQuery();

                   while(rs.next())
                   {
                       System.out.println("hi22");
                       jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("curr_no"));
                       jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("receive_date"));
                   }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i complete that task on 20th itself. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

try to surround ur code with try and catch

try{
  pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

```
           rs=pst.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next())
           {
               System.out.println("hi22");
           jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("curr_no"));
           jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("receive_date"));
           }
```

}catch(Exception e){}